# How do I correctly use the built-in current sensor in a Yaskawa J1000?

Tags: current-measurement, induction-motor

I am working on a test bed using a [Yaskawa J1000.](https://mobile.yaskawa.com/delegate/getAttachment?documentId=SIEPC71060631&cmd=documents&documentName=SIEPC71060631.pdf) I need to measure current flowing through to the motor. The manual mentions the analog ammeter outputs of the driver. When I connect them to a display, it shows some incredibly low value, although the current flowing is around 0.75A. Can someone tell me what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: You can embed hyperlinks to both the Yaskawa thing and its manual if you think it might help you get a better answer. Ditto the display you mention. *Incredibly low values* might mean anything so please list the value and list the full-scale of the meter/display range used.

Comment: Yes, it was about 0.05A.

Comment: Were you looking at the "analog monitor output" mentioned on page 45 of the [Yasakawa J1000 manual?](https://mobile.yaskawa.com/delegate/getAttachment?documentId=SIEPC71060631&cmd=documents&documentName=SIEPC71060631.pdf)

Comment: On page 35 of the manual, I am talking about the segment <7>. It says, Monitor outputs work with devices such as analog frequency meters, ammeters, voltmeters and wattmeters; they are not intended for use as a feedback-type of signal. I used an ammeter to measure the output but it wasn't the right current

Comment: Same thing.  OK.

Comment: Yep, you are right. Connection across AM and AC

Answer (score 3):

The output you are looking at is not a direct reading output.

From page 35 of the manual:

[image]

That's a signal that can be programmed to represent certain parameters.  You can't connect an ammeter to it and get any kind of reasonable measurement.

From page 45 of the manual:

[image]

It is an analog signal that varies from 0 to 10VDC.  It appears to be produced by an eight bit DAC.

Refer to page 198 for information an programming the function of the output:

[image]

You need to select the signal to monitor and program a gain and offset.

The parameters you can monitor are given on pages 203 and 204.  That's parameters U1-01 through U1-26.  Not all parameters can be sent to the analog monitor output.  Output current would be U1-03 (page 203.)

I would set the gain to 1 and the offset to zero.  The current would be measured directly from the AM output.

Comment: Thank you very much